# How to solve systems of linear equations for x, y in terms of a, b, c , d

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ad - bc \neq 0$.

The system is:
$$ ax + by = 1 \\
cx + dy = 2$$

I couldn't get far with elimination. I heard you could do this with row reduction, but i'd like an algebraic answer to this. Using substitution, solving for y in the first equation i get $y = \frac{1 - ax}{b}$. Plugging this into the second yields: $cx + \frac{d(1 - ax)}{b} = 2$.

Now, when solving for x, i can get as far as $cx * b = 2b - d(1 - ax)$. But once i get to this point i'm quite stuck as to what to do next.

Is there a better way to solve this? Am i on the right track? A walk through would be really nice--i have similar to answer.

Comment: You're on the right track. You have $bcx = 2b - ad + adx$, and you can separate the $x$ and express it in terms of $a,b,c,d$. Substituting it back to the $y = \frac{1-ax}{b}$ equation you got earlier should give you the $y$.

Comment: Gaussian Elimination = Row reduction, no?

Comment: @user121947 Have you studied matrices yet?

Comment: @DavidH I have not. It was expected to use algebraic techniques only; I do not mind taking the next step to learn. But i'd like to know how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one of the equations and express $x$ in terms of $y$.  Here's the first one:

$$ax+by=1 \to x=\frac{1-by}{a}.$$

Now substitute this expression for $x$ into the second:

$$c \frac{1-by}{a} + dy = 2 \\ \frac{c}{a} - \frac{bcy}{a} + dy = 2 \\ \left(d - \frac{bc}{a}\right)y = 2 - \frac{c}{a} \\ y = \frac{2 - \frac{c}{a}}{d - \frac{bc}{a}} = \frac{2a - c}{da - bc}.$$

Then

$$x = \frac{1 - b{\frac{2a - c}{da - bc}}}{a} = \frac{(da-bc) - b}{(da-bc)a}.$$

That's the straightforward way to solve it.

Comment: Or to get $x$, multiply first equation by $d$, second by $b$, and substract. It is the same with $y$. (I do not consider this comment worthy of being a full answer)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably via [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Your solution is:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= \dfrac{
\det \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & b\\
2 & d
\end{array} 
\right]
}{ad-bc} = \dfrac{d-2b}{ad-bc}\\
y &= \dfrac{
\det \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & 1\\
c & 2
\end{array} 
\right]
}{ad-bc} = \dfrac{2a-c}{ad-bc}
\end{align}
$$